# Routing issues in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and I came across an issue I can't get around. I did see other people asking the same question, however their problem had to do with a missing **['ngRoute']** .I checked the code many times,but I might have missed something so I'm really hoping I can get some help on this one. Thanks in advance !

*directories*  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvaqU.png

**firstpage.html** :

```
<html ng-app="myApp"> 
    <head>

    </head>
        <body> 
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script 
            src="angular.min.js">
        </script> 
        <script 
            src="angular-route.js">
        </script> 

        <script
            src="test.js">
        </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

**test.js** :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                    {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
                    })
                .when('/view2',
                    {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
                    })
                .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
            });

        var controllers = {};
        controllers.SimpleController = function ($scope) {
            $scope.djs=[{name:'Adam Beyer',city:'Sweden',djRank:1},
                            {name:'Joseph Capriati',city:'Napoli',djRank:4},
                            {name:'Nina Kraviz',city: 'Moscow',djRank:7},
                            {name:'Adam Petrov',city:'Sofia',djRank:100}];

            $scope.addCustomer() = function () {
                $scope.djs.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,
                                city:$scope.newCustomer.city});
            };
        };
        app.controller(controllers);
```

**View1.html** :

```
<div class = "container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
        Name: 
        <br/>   
        <input ng-model="filter.name" />
        <br/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="dj in djs|filter:filter.name|orderBy:'djRank'"> {{dj.name}} 
            </li>
        </ul>

        <br/>
        Customer Name: <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" />
        <br/>
        Customer City: <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model = "customer.city" />
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
</div>
```

**View2.html** :

```
 <div class="container">
    <h2>View 2</h2>
    City:
    <br/>
    <input type = "text" ng-model="city" />
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat= "dj in djs |filter:city"</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Does the console give any errors?

Comment: I recreated your code in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ml4g2q7exva0WEu9tiGn?p=preview) and I can't see anything wrong, other than you not having a link in either view that would switch to the other.... can you elaborate on what exactly your issue is?

Comment: Look in your browser's JavaScript console. That's where the errors will be

Comment: @Claies you should look in the console ~ *"angular.js:12722 TypeError: $scope.addCustomer is not a function"*

Comment: @Phil that is definitely an error with the button, but the *question* suggests a problem with routing and provides no additional information.  there are **multiple** other issues with the code *not* related to routing, but the OP isn't clear here which issue it is that is the one they are trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: The problem is that when I open the "firstpage.html" file I don't get redirected to the "Partials/View1.html" and I get a blank page. What's more, when I open the "View1.html" file the following page is open : http://i.imgur.com/UE3unaO.png?1 . Like I said,I'm new to Angular,but I assume there's an issue with the routing and that's why I'm not getting the expected results.

Comment: the issue you are describing there isn't reproducible in the plunker I posted, though there are other errors.  you should check the console for errors and determine if there is something in your local configuration that differs from the code you posted here.  after you solve the routing, you will definitely need to correct some issues with your `addCustomer` function, though....

Comment: @RadoslavNaidenov It will be very helpful if you can post a screenshot of the error console. Similar to the others, I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine.

Comment: @yihangho I'm not really using the console. I was just following a tutorial when I got to this part and realized I wasn't getting the expected results. I was expecting to have the dj names from the controller displayed instead of just {{dj.name}}.

Comment: @RadoslavNaidenov I what meant is the JavaScript console in your browser. It will log any errors that happened and will be very help in debugging your JavaScript code in general. Google "<browser you're using> JavaScript console" to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @yihangho Sorry about that ! I just opened the console and there are quite a few errors. Here is the screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/DBSKpJP.png

Comment: you *cannot* use routing from the local file system.  you **must** use a web server to use routing.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance ,guys ! I'll try to use a web server now and I hope I get what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo in your controller. It should be

```
$scope.addCustomer = function () {
    $scope.djs.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,
                     city:$scope.newCustomer.city});
};
```

not

```
$scope.addCustomer() = function () {
    $scope.djs.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,
                     city:$scope.newCustomer.city});
};
```

Notice the parentheses right after `addCustomer` should not be there.

Comment: this is indeed an error in the code, but it doesn't explain the routing issue the OP is asking about and has clarified in their comments...

Comment: Right, that comment wasn't there yet when I posted the answer.